# Why after adding and removing many WinForms controls the memory in use grows?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have the following code inside a WinForms application's `button1_Click()` event handler. I've noticed that the app starts with 4MB in use and after clicking on `button1` the memory raises at 12.5MB forever.

Why?

I've checked `GC.Collect()` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx) but it looks like I am using the right `Collect()` method overload.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9000; i++)
{
    if (Controls.Count > 0)
    {
        Controls[0].Dispose();
    }

    Controls.Clear();

    Button testButton = new Button();
    testButton.Text = "Test";

    panel1.Controls.Add(testButton);
}

GC.Collect();
```

Comment: Because your 9000 buttons need that much of memory. Or do I misunderstand your question? BTW; You are only disposing the first Control as you clear the `Controls` collection after the first dispose. But you should not have to call the `Dispose` by yourself. The garbage collector will (a little after the removing) call it by itself.

Comment: You have basically measured the minimum working set size of the GC heap.  At 4 MB you haven't yet even used half of the gen#0 segment.  Pages are added as you allocate, after the Collect call you'll have complete pages for the gen#0, gen#1 and gen#2 segments.  #0 and 1 will be empty and fill back up by future allocations.  12.5 MB is peanuts in any .NET program.  Favor a memory profiler to gather facts and avoid looking at working set, it is not a representative number for what the GC does.